# Google Maps v3 AutoComplete get the Suggestions

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am trying to use autocomplete in Google Maps. I am getting the results. but i want to college the results and feed it to my themes Autocomplete Plugin to make it look better. I am not able to get the list of the places as a modifiable variable array.

```
    var zoomLevel = 13;
    var lat = 13.00487;
    var lng = 77.576729;


    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: zoomLevel,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    var input = document.getElementById('search-google-places');

    var options = {
  types: ['geocode']
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request the [**autocompleteService**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_autocomplete_service) directly instead of using a places.Autocomplete, the response will give you the predictions.

Comment: My experience is that the results of autocompleteService and autocomplate are different. And there's also a difference if you omit the seperating colon between for example the street and the city ... it does not find anything in autocompleteservice because it does not use similarity. Or do you have an example where the results of "Theodor-Heuss-Allee Frankfurt am Main is equal in both the Service and the autocomplete-field?

Comment: When using a basic Autocomplete and retrieving the service-results via getPlacePredictions() I get exactly the same 3 results:     Theodor-Heuss-Allee, Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland; Maritim Hotel Frankfurt am Main, Theodor-Heuss-Allee, Frankfurt, Germany; American Express Payment Serv. Limited, Zweigniederlassung Frankfurt am Main, Theodor-Heuss-Allee, Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland